# Select rows with at least one instance of the where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. I have the following query that selects all rows with at least one 1.

```
select * from numbers where n1 = '1' OR n2 = '1'
```

How do I select rows with at least one 1 and one 2?

For example, if my table is like so -

```
n1 n2
1  1 
1  1
1  2
1  1
2  1
2  2
```

I would want the following output because these are the only two rows with at least one 1 and one 2.

```
n1 n2
1  2
2  1
```

I cannot do the following because this will also select rows with only one's and only two's.

```
select * from numbers where n1 = '1' OR n2 = '1' OR n1 = '2' OR n2 = '2'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just describe the two possible combinations, like:

```
select * 
from numbers 
where (n1 = 1 and n2 = 2) or (n1 = 2 and n2 = 1)
```

Assuming that `1` and `2` are the only possible values, as shown in your sample data, then this would also work:

```
where least(n1, n2) = 1 and greatest(n1, n2) = 2
```

Under the same assumption, better yet (as commented by [Jonnix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jonnix)):

```
where n1 + n2 = 3
```

Comment: Under that same assumption, I suppose `WHERE n1 + n2 = 3` would also work?

Comment: @Jonnix: sure, and it's more elegant, added it to my answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have two columns and two values, you can do:

```
where (n1, n2) in ( (1, 2), (2, 1) )
```

Tuples can be very handy.